# Receive ajax get with dot parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, binding

I have this url

https://localhost:44318/Warehouse/IsNameExist?Warehouse.namewh=Warehouse+I

how to bind namewh parameter to controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> IsNameExist(string namewh)
    {
        return new JsonResult(namewh);
    }
```

but is this only return null value.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
[FromUri(Name = "Warehouse.Name")]string Name
```

as parameter.